# Facing imagepullbackoff error inside k8s 3 node cluster on local company server

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ecr

I have created a 3-node Kubernetes cluster, but my Jenkins-based CI/CD process is stuck in an ImagePullBackOff state. I have built the image on a worker node but master can not fetch the image, and I get an error of ImagePullBackOff.  For some micro-services it works fine by pulling the image from worker node, and for some not.

`kubectl describe pod` shows:

```
Events:


 Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  38s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned dis-serv-ns/dis-serv-deploy-7c54ddb67c-tbbqg to kubernetes-worker2
  Normal   Pulling    20s (x2 over 36s)  kubelet            Pulling image "disc-server:latest"
  Warning  Failed     17s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "disc-server:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for disc-server, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  Warning  Failed     17s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    2s (x2 over 33s)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "disc-server:latest"
  Warning  Failed     2s (x2 over 33s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: Is your CI process actually pushing the built image anywhere (you've tagged this with ECR, for example)?  You should not generally directly connect to the worker nodes.  Build the images in Jenkins, push them to ECR, and use the (long) ECR image name in your Kubernetes manifests.

Comment: I agree with what @David Maze suggested. Your CI/CD pipeline should push images to a central registry like ECR but I guess in your case the image is present on one node and your pod got scheduled on an another node. Therefore it is not able to find it locally. For some services it worked because their Pods got scheduled in the same node where the image is present.

Comment: How can I check that where pod is scheduled?

Comment: But inside the cluster all the node are communicating with each other then image on any node can be accessible?

Comment: @DavidMaze I also build and push the image into ECR and then use it inside the manifest file  the whole process is done through Jenkins I face the same issue after this?

Comment: Nodes never pull images from each other.  If a given node doesn't have an image it needs then it pulls it from the registry specified in the image name (or Docker Hub if none is given).

Comment: @DavidMaze but in my case what will be the solution?

Comment: @DavidMaze Pod is schedule on worker2 but image is available on Worker that's a reason it not pull the image!

Comment: @DavidMaze I also push the image on ECR and try to pull it but it give the me the same error?

Comment: I have fixed this error by updating the ECR secrets and also update after 12 hours time using cron job.

Answer (score -1):

The following are the reason due to which imagepullbackoff error face.
1: ECR Token expire after 12 hours that's a reason imagePullbackoff error occurs. So we need to update the token in case off when we are pulling the images from ECR inside k8s cluster.
2: When the image is not available inside the repository. when the image name is not correct.